Visualisation of Projective quadrics
I'm stuck at extracting the geometric picture of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ in the following example from my textbook.
Example 3.10:
For $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ the only nontrivial equation using the Segre embedding ($\Sigma$) is $z_{00}z_{11} - z_{01}z_{10}$. So $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 = Z(z_{00}z_{11} - z_{01}z_{10}) \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ is a quadric. $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ contains two families of lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$: $\{ p \} \times \mathbb{P}^1$ and $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \{ q \}$ for all $p, q \in \mathbb{P}^1$.
My questions are;

Why $\mathbb{P}^1$ is drawn as parallel lines on the left? I thought lines are intersecting at the origin in $\mathbb{P}$.
How can I imagine $\{ p \} \times \mathbb{P}^1$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$?

I know that it's a cartesian product $\{ p \} \times \mathbb{P}^1$ so that I'm imagining a horizonal line with a set of vertical lines on the left figure at the moment. But I'm not sure how this translates to the right figure in $\mathbb{P}^3$... So, can you tell me which line(s) corresponds to this particular $\{ p \} \times \mathbb{P}^1$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$?





Slow down. What is $\Bbb P$? What is the origin to which you refer? Remember what a cartesian product is: ${p}\times \Bbb P^1$ is of course a projective line (abstractly).

@TedShifrin Thank you! Fixed the typo about $\mathbb{P}^1$! Yeah, I know that it's a cartesian product ${ p } \times \mathbb{P}^1$ so that I'm imagining a horizonal line with a set of vertical lines on the left at the moment. But I'm not sure how this translates to the right figure in $\mathbb{P}^3$...

I've edited my post a little more.

@Shrugs Got it! Thanks!

What is the image of such a $\Bbb P^1$ under the Segre embedding mapping to $\Bbb P^3$?

Definition that I have about Segre embedding is $\sigma : \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m \to \mathbb{P}^N ; ([a_0, ..., a_n], [b_0, ..., b_m]) \mapsto [a_ib_j]{ij}$. Thus, the cartesian product ${ p } \times \mathbb{P}^1$ will be mapped to $[a_i b_j]{ij}$ for fixed $[a_0, \dots, a_n]$ with varying $[b_0, \dots, b_m]$... But still I can't imagine what this looks like in $\mathbb{P}^3$....

Here's another hint that may help. Suppose that $p$is a fixed point on $\mathbb P^1$. So it has homogeneous coordinates $p=[p_0,p_1]$ for some (fixed, not both zero) numbers $p_0,p_1$. Then the points of ${p} \times \mathbb P^1$ can be parametrised as  $\left( [p_0,p_1], [s,t] \right)$ where $s$ and $t$ vary...

For simplicity let's restrict to the open set $s \neq 0$: then you can write this as $\left( [p_0,p_1], [1,t] \right)$. According to your formula for the Segre embedding, the image of such a point in $\mathbb P^3$ has coordinates $[p_0,p_0t,p_1,p_1t]$. Letting $t$ take all values in $\mathbb C$ (or whatever your field in), what kind of subset do you get this way?

@LazzaroCampeotti That totally makes sense! Thank you so much! So, by varying $t$, we'd get a set of points $[p_0, p0 t, p_1, p_1 t]$ with scaled 2nd and 4th coordinates by $t$. Now, I'm trying to interpret this set in $\mathbb{P}^3$, but I'm stuck at having a geometry picture. Like in other projective spaces, in $\mathbb{P}^3$, $[p_0, p1, p_2, p_3] = \lambda [p_0, p1, p_2, p_3] \ \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. So, does thsi mean that the set we just got is just a union of two axes (2nd and 4th coordinates) in $\mathbb{A}^4 \supset \mathbb{P}^3$?
